# Changing css class for li element problems

Tags: jquery, css

I have the following structure :

```
<ul id='myTopicsList'>

<li> 
<a><span> First Element </span></a>
</li>

.....

</ul>
```

The first time the page is loaded the first li will be selected by highliting it to background color blue.

The next time the user clicks another element in the list it should change to blue and the rest should have white background.

I am using this script :

```
function GetMyTopic(catID) {
 $('#myTopicsList li').each(function () {

        if ($(this).attr('id').indexOf(catID) > 0) {
            $(this).addClass('SideBarBoxliSelected');
        }
        else {
            $(this).addClass('SideBarBoxli');
        }
    });
}
```

here the css :

```
.SideBarBoxli{margin-bottom:4px; background-color:#fafafa; height:22px; }
.SideBarBoxli:hover {background-color:#E3ECF8; cursor:pointer; }
.SideBarBoxliSelected{margin-bottom:4px; background-color:#6388BF; height:22px; }
```

When I click and assign the `SideBarBoxliSelected` class to the clicked `li` the background remains the same.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5):

Here is the html I would use:

```
<ul id="myTopicsList">
    <li class="SideBarBoxli SideBarBoxliSelected">first</li>
    <li class="SideBarBoxli">sec</li>
    <li class="SideBarBoxli">three</li>
    <li class="SideBarBoxli">four</li>
    <li class="SideBarBoxli">fiffff</li>
</ul>
```

Here is the code I would use:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('ul#myTopicsList li').click(function() {
        $('li.SideBarBoxliSelected').removeClass('SideBarBoxliSelected');
        $(this).addClass('SideBarBoxliSelected');
    });
});
```

The `.click` function will set it so that whenever someone clicks on any of the `li` items they will trigger the anonymous function which removes the class `SideBarBoxliSelected` from the currently selected one and adds it to the clicked item.

### Edit

---

You can also add the following to make sure the first item has the class `SideBarBoxliSelected` on page load:

```
$('ul#myTopicsList li:first').addClass('SideBarBoxliSelected');
```

The above line would go on the line before the `$('ul#myTopicsList li').click` call.

---

Comment: ul#myTopicList should be ul#myTopicsList fyi

Comment: I have applied the code u've posted. but when the page loads for the first time, the first li has its background #fafafa and not blue(#E3ECF8).

I have on each li element an onclick event calls GetMyTopic and passes the catID to do other work.

hmmm...

Comment: ok, clicking on each item works correctly. remains when the page is loaded first time, the first element is not selected

Comment: Any idea why when the page is first loaded the first element isn't highlighted blue?

Comment: @Joseph Ghassan, can you please share with us your actual code so that we can try to better help you resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#myTopicsList li').click( function() {
        $('#myTopicsList li').removeClass('SideBarBoxliSelected');
        $(this).addClass('SideBarBoxliSelected');
    });
});
```

Comment: Perfect! it is working here. one thing remains though. When the page is first loaded the first element is not selected though its class is class="SideBarBoxli SideBarBoxliSelected".

Answer (score 0):

When is GetMyTopic called? I would suggest using the Firebug plugin for Firefox to debug your javascript. Make sure the right CSS class is being applied to each LI involved in your test case. If not, you can figure out why by stepping through the script in the debugger. You can also check out the CSS in firebug to see what styles are getting applied.

Also, in your sample code you are using the 'id' attribute to identify list items, but you don't have an id attribute defined in your HTML or script. Maybe something is getting left out?

Comment: GetMyTopic is called when an li element is clicked. I have assigned it to the onclick event of li.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure using the indexOf function is the best way to compare the id to your passed in variable.  Maybe try using:

```
if ($(this).attr('id') == catID)
```

instead?

Comment: The reason why I am using indexOf is that each li has the following id pattern : myCat{0} where {0} is the placeholder of id.

Comment: Ah, i see - so the actual ID is part of a bigger string.  In any case, samandmoore's suggestion above is a better solution.  I would go with what he suggests.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add the period in front of "SideBarBoxliSelected" so `.SideBarBoxliSelected`

Answer (score 0):

This is the simplest way to do it.

HTML

```
<ul id="myTopicsList">
    <li>first</li>
    <li>second</li>
    <li>third</li>
    <li>fourth</li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
#myTopicsList li {background:#fafafa;margin-bottom:4px;height:22px;}
#myTopicsList li:hover {background:#E3ECF8;cursor:pointer;}
#myTopicsList li.active {background:#6388BF;}
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#myTopicsList li').click(function(e){
        // remove all active classes
        $('#myTopicsList li').removeClass('active');
        // add active class to clicked item
        $(this).addClass('active');
    });
    // click on the first item on page load
    $('#myTopicsList li').eq(0).click();
});
```